# Creating Instances for classification-Weka

Tags: java, weka

i have a question. I have a java app thats classifying instances from real world, and i have it storage in double[][], my question is this:

```
Instance iExample = new Instance(4); 
iExample.setValue((Attribute)fvWekaAttributes.elementAt(0), 1.0);       
iExample.setValue((Attribute)fvWekaAttributes.elementAt(1), 0.5);       
iExample.setValue((Attribute)fvWekaAttributes.elementAt(2), "gray"); 
iExample.setValue((Attribute)fvWekaAttributes.elementAt(3), "positive");
```

This is the example given to create an instance, but since i am classifying the instance does it it need the last element(3-ClassAtribute), which is the class that i want to be labeled/predicted? What do i put?A empty string?

```
iExample.setValue((Attribute)fvWekaAttributes.elementAt(3), "");
```

I want to be able to label the instance and get distribution for instance.

Thanks in advance

J.S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set an attribute's value in an `Instance` to be unspecified by using `myInstance.setMissing(int attributeIndex)`